# How can we get the attributes of an wrapped object, obj, when the wrapper __getattribute__ calls obj's __getitem__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, wrapper, getattr

Suppose `DotDict` is a wrapper class which allows you to access the wrapped object's 
`__getitem__` method through `__getattr__`

Suppose `obj` is not an instance of `DotDict`, and the following
is true about `obj`:

```
obj.a  returns 'apple'
obj[a] returns 999
```

Now we wrap the object in a DotDict:

```
wobj = DotDict(obj)
```

`wobj.a` now returns the same value as `obj[a]`, 999.
`obj.a` is much harder to get.

```
class DotDict():

    def __init__(self, true_self):
        assert (not inspect.isclass(true_self))
        object.__setattr__(self, 'true_self', true_self)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        return true_self[attr_name]
```

## One flawed approach:

One approach, would be to allow the user to introduce an underscore at the beginning of the attribute name:
if `_a` is also a valid key to `obj.__getitem__`, try:

```
x = wobj.__a
x = wobj.___a
x = wobj.____a
x = wobj._____a
```

... and so on.

```
  def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
            true_self = object.__getattribute__(self, 'true_self')
            try:
                return true_self[attr_name]
            except KeyError:
                # there is a __getitem__ method,
                # but attr_name is not a valid key
                pass
            try:                
                attr_name = attr_name.lstrip('_')
                attr = getattr(true_self, attr_name)
                return attr
            except AttributeError:
                # if "a" is not an attribute of obj, then raise an exception
                raise AttributeError
```

Trying more underscores will not cause an infinite loop.
An exception will be thrown if `___...___a` is not a valid key
to `obj.__getitem__`, and `obj` has no attribute named `a`
Only those attributes of `obj` whose name do not begin with an underscore are accessible through `wobj`

A problem with this approach is that if `wobj.___a` returns something, how we know whether we just got `obj[___a]` or `obj.a`?
How can we differentiate the results returned by `__getattribute__`?

## Below is a little demo script:

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self):      
        self.a = 'attribute a, not getitem'
        self.c = list()
        s = 'a'
        for k in range(0, 10):
            s = '_' + s
            self.c.append(s)

def __getitem__(self, key):
    print('__getitem__ was called')
    if key in self.c:
        return '__getitem__' + key
    else:
        raise KeyError

obj = DemoClass()
ddobj = DotDict(obj)
attr_name = 'a'
try:
    count_underscores = 0
    while True:
        attr = getattr(ddobj, attr_name)
        print('potential attr == ', attr)
        attr_name = '_' + attr_name
        count_underscores += 1
except AttributeError:
    print('there is no attribute named ', attr_name.lstrip('_'))

print('count_underscores == ', count_underscores)
print('attr == ', attr)
```

Comment: Instead of returning `value`, can you instead return `(source, value)`, where `source` distinguishes the two? Can you instead throw an error if both `a['foo']` and `a.foo` exist?

Comment: If you need the underlying object's attributes, why are you wrapping it in a `DotDict` in the first place? Just keep attributes and items separate.

Comment: @user2357112 Most of the time we want `obj`'s `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods. We can access these very easily through the wrapped objects dot-operator. However, once a blue moon, we really will want an attribute of `obj`. At times like this, we no longer have direct access to `obj`, only to the wrapped object.